# inner join just performs merge line by line?

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have these two files:

**first file**: `'ast'`

*columns*: `fid,CAD_ADMIN`

**second file**: `'inte'`

*columns*: `Left_Ln, Right_Ln`

---

**Purpose**

I want to do a join with `fid` and `Left_Ln` and  fill a new column in the `inte` file called `Left_enot` with the `CAD_ADMIN` column of the first file.

and then the same but with Right_Ln and  fill a new column in the `inte` file called `Left_enot` with the `CAD_ADMIN` column of the first file.

I did this:

```
import pandas as pd


ast = pd.read_csv(filename,encoding = 'UTF-8')
inte = pd.read_csv(filename1,encoding = 'UTF-8')
ast.reset_index(inplace= True)
ast.rename(columns = {'index': 'FID_1'},inplace = True)
final = pd.merge(ast, inte, left_on='FID_1', right_on="Left_Ln", how='inner')
print(final)
```

But it just merges line by line with no regard to the `fid` and `Left_Ln'. What I need is like the UPDATE in sql. For example to find the corresponding values from one field to the other:

How the files look like:

first file

```
FID_1 CAD_ADMIN
0     921095
1     921094
2     921093
3     921092
4     921091
5     921090
```

second file

```
FID_1  Left_Ln  Right_Ln
    0       0        0
    1       0        0
    2       0        0
    3       0        0
    4       0        0
    5       0        0  (thousands of lines)
```